# Is std::time::Duration as precise as time::precise_time_ns from "time" crate?

Tags: time, rust

For a long time, standard way to precisely measure time in Rust was `time` crate and its [`time::precise_time_ns`](https://docs.rs/time/0.1.42/time/fn.precise_time_ns.html) function. However, `time` crate is deprecated now, and `std` library has [`std::time::Instant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html) intended for measuring elapsed time.

I'm not sure it has the same precision, at least by design. I know it might be a vague question because there are different implementation of both things for different OSes, and implementations may change in different versions, but at least do they have the same purpose? Is `std::time::Duration` a correct replacement for `time::precise_time_ns` at least from the viewpoint of their design?

Running this script on my system (Mac OS) outputs quite small durations, so it's probably quite precise:

```rust
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let mut t = Instant::now();
    loop {
        println!("{:?}", t.elapsed());
        t = Instant::now();
    }
}
```

```
40ns
42ns
41ns
45ns
40ns
41ns
40ns
40ns
41ns
41ns
41ns
40ns
40ns
40ns
```

Comment: At least on Linux, [they](https://github.com/rust-lang-deprecated/time/blob/324d2eb89354c412f520dbb29ef2c812085010a9/src/sys.rs#L172) [both](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/53f2165c544cceeafb308b80ace656ed328c1dc2/src/libstd/sys/unix/time.rs#L369) use `clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` so they should give the same results.

Comment: The implementation is platform-specific, so you will probably need to compare the code for the relevant platforms yourself. The general code quality of the Rust standard library is high, so my base assumption would be that the implementation in `std::time` is as accurate as the target platform allows.

Comment: Looks like the documentation could be improved. It should either state a guaranteed precision or explicitly explain that no guarantees are given. There is [this very relevant issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32626).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with high certainty, `std::time::Instant` is a correct replacement for `time::precise_time_ns`, having the same, or better, precision.

As of Rust 1.33.0, `time` 0.1.41, implementations for most OSes of `time::precise_time_ns()` and `std::time::Instant::now()` are the same, with few exceptions.

- **Unix**: *same*, `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)`
- **MacOS**: *same*, `mach_absolute_time`
- **Windows**: *same*, `QueryPerformanceCounter`
- **Wasm32**: `time` has no implementation, `std` uses `TimeSysCall::perform(TimeClock::Monotonic)`
- **Redox**: *same*, the same as unix
- **SGX**: *implementations differ*, probably `std` has more correct implementation

It's unlikely that in future versions `std::time::Instant::now` implementations will worsen.

## Details of implementations

[`time` crate has all implementations in single file](https://github.com/rust-lang-deprecated/time/blob/0.1.41/src/sys.rs), with cfg flags, standard library has directory per system, with [mod.rs where implementation is chosen at compile time](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.33.0/src/libstd/sys/mod.rs) (unix also has conditional compilation for mac os inside `time.rs`).

### Unix, "regular", *not* MacOS or iOS

Both implementations use `clock_gettime (3)` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` `clock_id`.

#### time

`#[cfg(all(not(target_os = "macos"), not(target_os = "ios")))]`

```
let mut ts = libc::timespec { tv_sec: 0, tv_nsec: 0 };
unsafe {
    libc::clock_gettime(libc::CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &mut ts);
}
(ts.tv_sec as u64) * 1000000000 + (ts.tv_nsec as u64)
```

#### std

`#[cfg(unix)]` + `#[cfg(not(any(target_os = "macos", target_os = "ios")))]`

```
Instant { t: now(libc::CLOCK_MONOTONIC) }
```

### Unix, MacOS or iOS

Both implementations use `mach_absolute_time`.

BTW, standard `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)` works on my system too, Mac OS 10.13.6, but I'm not sure if it's really monotonic.

#### time

`#[cfg(any(target_os = "macos", target_os = "ios"))]`

```
unsafe {
    let time = libc::mach_absolute_time();
    let info = info();
    time * info.numer as u64 / info.denom as u64
}
```

#### std

`#[cfg(unix)]` + `#[cfg(any(target_os = "macos", target_os = "ios"))]`

```
Instant { t: unsafe { libc::mach_absolute_time() } }
```

### Windows

Both implementations use [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx)

#### time

`#[cfg(windows)]`

```
let mut ticks = i64_to_large_integer(0);
unsafe {
    assert!(QueryPerformanceCounter(&mut ticks) == 1);
}
mul_div_i64(large_integer_to_i64(ticks), 1000000000, frequency()) as u64
```

#### std

`#[cfg(windows)]`

```
let mut t = Instant { t: 0 };
cvt(unsafe {
    c::QueryPerformanceCounter(&mut t.t)
}).unwrap();
t
```

### Wasm32

It's probably for non-web use, and unrelated to [web-sys](https://crates.io/crates/web-sys). It `time` crate it's unimplemented.

#### time

`#[cfg(all(target_arch = "wasm32", not(target_os = "emscripten")))]`

```
unimplemented!()
```

#### std

`#[cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")]`

```
Instant(TimeSysCall::perform(TimeClock::Monotonic))
```

### Redox

Both implementations use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)`, the same as for unux.

#### time

`#[cfg(target_os = "redox")]`

```
let mut ts = syscall::TimeSpec { tv_sec: 0, tv_nsec: 0 };
syscall::clock_gettime(syscall::CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &mut ts).unwrap();
(ts.tv_sec as u64) * 1000000000 + (ts.tv_nsec as u64)
```

#### std

`#[cfg(target_os = "redox")]`

```
Instant { t: now(syscall::CLOCK_MONOTONIC) }
```

### SGX

Here implementations differ. `time` crate falls back to std, and uses non-monotonic time (there was no monotonic time in std at the time, probably). Probably migrating from time to std improves accuracy because it uses SGX-specific call.

#### time

`#[cfg(target_env = "sgx")]`

```
// This unwrap is safe because current time is well ahead of UNIX_EPOCH, unless system clock is adjusted backward.
let std_duration = SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap();
std_duration.as_secs() * NANOS_PER_SEC + std_duration.subsec_nanos() as u64
```

#### std

`#[cfg(all(target_vendor = "fortanix", target_env = "sgx"))]`

```
Instant(usercalls::insecure_time())
```